# change option data value in select2 ajax tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have this code for select2 tags method using ajax:

json data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5",
        "text": "laravel3"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "text": "laravel2"
    }
]
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tag_list').select2({
        placeholder: "Choose tags...",
        tags: true,
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
            if ($(data).filter(function() {
                return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
            }).length === 0) {
                return {
                    id: term,
                    text: term
                };
            }
        },
        ajax: {
            url: '/tags/find',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: $.trim(params.term)
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            delay: 250,
            cache: true
        }
    });
});
```

With my code I can search and select data from database or add new tag to my select2 area. Now when I select data from database, `<option value="">` is data `id` but when I add new tag `<option value="">` is `name`(text) like this:

[image]

Now I need to change option `value` (get database data) from data `id` to data `name` (text). How do change option data value from id to name?!

Comment: How are you adding the `newtag` option to your select2 dropdown?

Comment: @Terry `newtag` is type a newtag and enter...

Comment: @LaraBell at what use you are using select box?.. it might be submitting data to server right?...that time you need id's instead of text...so preserving id's as values is better.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** I've added more background and references to the docs, and switched the JSFiddle to using `$.map()` as the docs do.

[The Select2 data format](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats) is described in the docs:

> Select2 expects a very specific data format [...] Select2 requires that each object contain an `id` and a `text` property. [...] Select2 generates the `value` attribute from the `id` property of the data objects ...

The docs also describe [how to use something other than your `id`](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#transforming-data-into-the-required-format):

> If you use a property other than `id` (like `pk`) to uniquely identify an option, you need to map your old property to `id` before passing it to Select2.  If you cannot do this on your server or you are in a situation where the API cannot be changed, you can do this in JavaScript before passing it to Select2

In your case, this would mean transforming the `data` you get back from your AJAX call, so that the `id` element of each result is actually the `text` value.

You can do that with [the `processResults()` AJAX option](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data).  To do that using `$.map` as the docs do:

```
processResults: function (data) {
    return {
        // Transform data, use text as id
        results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
            obj.id = obj.text;
            return obj;
        })
    };
}
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/dwczf9tx/).  Note I've set it up to simulate your real AJAX request using JSFiddle's `/echo/json` async option.

And here's a screenshot of the generated source, showing the `value` of both added tags, and those retrieved via AJAX, are the name (`text`):

[image: Generated Select2 options]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ajax: {
    url: '/tags/find',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            q: $.trim(params.term)
        };
    },
    //updated 
    processResults: function (data) {
        var newData = [];
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            newData.push({                        
                    id: item.id, //id part present in data                        
                    text: item.text //string to be displayed
            });
        });
        return { results: newData };
    },
    //
    delay: 250,
    cache: true
}
```